# How to customize table row height in Antd?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

Antd comes with a nices table component, but I cannot find anything in [the docs](https://ant.design/components/table/) about how to configure the "density" of the table, i.e., the default height of a table row, and maybe the font size as well.

By default the table has a spacey layout:

[image]

I have a use case that requires more smaller/dense rows (think of the density in typical spreadsheet programs like Excel).

I'm new to Antd, and I have no idea where to start. Do I need to customize Antd's CSS? What would be the right mechanism to achieve it, configuring heights on cell or row level, or rather messing with the padding? I was opting for Antd because I was hoping things like these don't require much CSS knowledge, am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can style your `Tag` from css. if you want to style [`antd table`](https://ant.design/components/table/), then you should target `antd` classes.

[image: antd-table-styles]

```
const columns =[
...
{
    title: "Tags",
    key: "tags",
    dataIndex: "tags",
    render: tags => (
      <span>
        {tags.map(tag => {
          let color = tag.length > 5 ? "geekblue" : "green";
          if (tag === "loser") {
            color = "volcano";
          }
          return (
            <Tag color={color} key={tag} className="my-tag">
              {tag.toUpperCase()}
            </Tag>
          );
        })}
      </span>
    )
  },
...
]
```

**css**

```
/* table */
.ant-table {
  font-size: 9px;
}

/* row data */
.ant-table-tbody > tr > td {
  height: 5px;
  padding: 4px;
}
/* row tags */
.my-tag {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.ant-table-thead > tr > th {
  height: 5px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

[image: Edit so-61044628-table-row-height-change]

Comment: I'm wondering if this is also possible using styled components? (I was told that is the way to go these days, and now I'm confused that it still seems necessary to mess with the usual CSS overrides for something like that).

Comment: yes! you have to target `antd classes` in styled-components too.

Comment: const LocalStyledTable = styled(Table)` ...style your antd classes`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! What is confusing my is that I can only style the `<Table>` component, but in terms of the DOM I want to style `<td>` or so. Probably it is just a matter of using appropriate child selectors like `table > tr > td` on the styled `styled(Table)`...

Comment: I think your question wasn't for styled components. For antd styling in styled components, post another question. if I get time I will solve it.

Comment: @bluenode10, when you use the pattern proposed by  @blueseal, you can not use `size` prop of `Table` component, or your custom style will just be ignored

Answer (score 6):

I have same problem here, and based on @blueseal answer, I did my line height with Styled-Components this way!

My JSX

```
 <MyTable rowKey="id" dataSource={list} columns={columns} />
```

MY CSS

```
import { Table } from 'antd'

export const MyTable = styled(Table)`
  tbody {
    tr {
      td {
        height: 5px;
        padding: 4px;
      }
    }
  }
`
```

I hope help someone!

Answer (score 2):

In the Ant-Design documentation you can find the way to change the size and appearance of the tables:

[image]

For example:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h4>Middle size table</h4>
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} size="middle" />
    <h4>Small size table</h4>
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} size="small" />
  </div>,
  mountNode,
);
```

The correct way to do it is by adding the size attribute which has middle and small as parameters. This detail only works in tables arranged within Modals, otherwise preferably not use the included classes for responsive design and add custom css modifiers.
For example, I am creating a payroll system where I apply Ant-Design, in the Employees table I show it using the responsive css classes as shown in the documentation:

[image]

And I apply the attribute size = "small" for the tables in the modals dialog:

[image]

Hoping that this knowledge will be of use to you.

Comment: Why does the small size work only in modal?

Comment: Because Ant Design Group designed the Cascading Style Sheets so that tables are strictly small so that they visually look that way in modal dialogs, instead you can place tables at any size as long as it's on the page. main website

Answer (score 1):

@Jorge Pirela solution solves the problem. Just add the size attribute inside the table component as seen below

```
 <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} size='small'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add vertical margins on any of your columns, that should do the trick:

```
render: (value) => (
  <span style={{display: 'flex', marginBottom: 5, marginTop: 5}}>{value}</span>
)
```